# Kurdish fonts are not properly displayed

Tags: android, fonts

I am building an app in three languages - english, kurdish and arabic. I have noticed the problem specifically in samsung devices in that the fonts are not displaying correctly. The image is shown below.
[image]

I have tried embedding fonts in the app but apparently the supplied font is not being used because both the fonts look different in the images. I am posting the code that I am using below -

```
public class FontUtils {
    private static String FONT_PATH="fonts/al-kwnd.TTF";

    private Activity activity;
    private Typeface tf;

    public FontUtils(Activity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), FONT_PATH);
    }
    public void setFont(TextView view){ 
        view.setTypeface(tf);
    }
    public void setFont(EditText view){
        view.setTypeface(tf);
    }
    public void setFont(Button view){
        view.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the device, you have to change the default font on the device that you are testing the app with. I had the same problem with Samsung devices. Stock android displays the fonts properly.